# Sns does not trigger lambda service

Tags: node.js, email, amazon-sns

My use case is to call customised template from SNS service.
It's hitting "app.js" but unable to call exports.handler function.

can someone please help me out and correct me.

PFB code :

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var aws     = require('aws-sdk'); 
aws.config.loadFromPath(__dirname + '/config.json');   
var ses = new aws.SES();
var fs = require("fs");
var email   = "abc@ss.co.uk";
var file = fs.readFileSync("template.html", "utf8");
```

Loaded the config and calling function.

```
exports.handler = function index(event, context, callback) {

 // SNS request is not comimg inside this method..  

 var SESMessage = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
 var feature = event.Records[0].Sns.Message.feature;

 console.log("SESMessage :::::" + SESMessage);

 var data= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(SESMessage));
 console.log(data);

 var template = Handlebars.compile(file);
 var result = template(data);

 var ses_mail = "From: 'ab' <" + email + ">\n";
 ses_mail = ses_mail + "To: " + email + "\n";
 ses_mail = ses_mail + "Subject: Meter Read Confirmation\n";
 ses_mail = ses_mail + "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
 ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
 ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n\n";
 ses_mail = ses_mail + result;

 var params = {
 RawMessage: { Data: new Buffer(ses_mail) },
 Destinations: [ email ],
 Source: "'Source name' <" + email + ">'"
 };

ses.sendRawEmail(params, function(err, data) {
if(err) {
    console.log("error :: " + err);
}
else {
    console.log("Success");
    // res.send(data);
}
});
}

var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
var host = server.address().address;
var port = server.address().port;

console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things wrong with the (lambda) code:

1. No need to create express app when writing lambda functions
2. By default, the lambda function is exported as *exports.handle* not *handlers* mind the `s` in handlers[image: Check the image & your AWS Console]
3. Lambda's timeout after the default timeout & are fired as soon the SNS topic triggers them, if they are subscribed to the topic

It would help you & us tremendously if you could share the **cloudwatch** logs under **lambda->functions->your function->monitoring->cloudwatch logs**

Comment: **module initialization error: TypeError
**at _addListener (events.js:216:11)
**at Server.addListener (events.js:276:10)
**at new Server (_http_server.js:234:10)
**at Object.exports.createServer (http.js:44:10)
**at Object.createServer (/var/task/node_modules/aws-serverless-express/index.js:144:25)
**at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:5:37)
**at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
**at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
**at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
**at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
**END RequestId: 934baefd-d59a-11e7-a645-45767ce8d455

Comment: But if I removed the lambda function i.e exports.handler then how I will receive and use the input from SNS.

Right now I am receving like 

**var feature = event.Records[0].Sns.Message.feature;**

Please correct if my approach is wrong.

Comment: along with the app.js are you exporting the node_modules you are importing in code?
if not trying zipping the app.js with the node_modules folder and upload it to Lambda.

Comment: What I suggested to use was 'exports.handle' instead of 'exports.handler'. And I have added the supporting image for you to check in your lambda console.

Comment: 'use strict';

const aws = require('aws-sdk'); 
aws.config.loadFromPath(__dirname + '/config.json');

const sns = new aws.SNS();
console.log("loading files...")


exports.handle = function index(event, context, callback) {

    console.log("::::: event handler ::::: " + event);
}

I have shortened code nad used handle but didn't work :(

Comment: That might be the root of the error. As in local development we have the modules ready to import into our express apps.
So, if you upload the node_modules folder with app.js, and refactor your code to suit lambda's style. It should be up and running in no time.